# Stringr str_which first compare 1st row with whole column than to next row

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I am trying to match DNA sequences in a column. I am trying to find the longer version of itself, but also in this column it has the same sequence.

I am trying to use Str_which for which I know it works, since if I manually put the search pattern in it finds the rows which include the sequence.

As a preview of the data I have:

```
SNID    type    seqs2
9584818 seqs    TCTTTCTTTAAGACACTGTCCCAAGCTGAAAGGGAACCTACCAAAGAAACTTCTTCATCTRAGGAATCTACTTATATGTGAGTGCAATGAACTTGTAGATTCTGCTCCTGGGGCCACAGAA
9584818 reversed    TTCTGTGGCCCCAGGAGCAGAATCTACAAGTTCATTGCACTCACATATAAGTAGATTCCTYAGATGAAGAAGTTTCTTTGGTAGGTTCCCTTTCAGCTTGGGACAGTGTCTTAAAGAAAGA
9562505 seqs    GTCTTCAGCATCTTTCTTTAAGACACTGTCCCAAGCTGAAAGGGAACCTACCAAAGAAACTTCTTCATCTRAGGAATCTACTTATATGTGAGTGCAATGAACTTGTAGATTCTGCTCCTGGGGCCACAGAACTTTGTGAAT
9562505 reversed    ATTCACAAAGTTCTGTGGCCCCAGGAGCAGAATCTACAAGTTCATTGCACTCACATATAAGTAGATTCCTYAGATGAAGAAGTTTCTTTGGTAGGTTCCCTTTCAGCTTGGGACAGTGTCTTAAAGAAAGATGCTGAAGAC
```

Using a simple search of row one as x

```
x <- "TCTTTCTTTAAGACACTGTCCCAAGCTGAAAGGGAACCTACCAAAGAAACTTCTTCATCTRAGGAATCTACTTATATGTGAGTGCAATGAACTTGTAGATTCTGCTCCTGGGGCCACAGAA"
str_which(df$seqs2, x)
```

I get the answer I expect:

```
> str_which(df$seqs3, x)
[1] 1 3
```

But when I try to search as a whole column, I just get the result of the rows finding itself. And not the other rows in which it is also stated.

```
> str_which(df$seqs2, df$seqs2)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Since my data set is quite large, I do not want to do this manually, and rather use the column as input, and not just state "x" first.

Anybody any idea how to solve this? I have tried most Stringr cmds by now, but by mistake I might have did it wrongly or skipped some important ones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to compare `dftest$seqs2[1]` with `df$seqs2[1]`,  `dftest$seqs2[2]` with `df$seqs2[2]` and so on? Can you provide 4 rows of `dftest` as well? What is your expected output?

Comment: I will edit this. The original file is a lot longer so I created a test df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need `lapply` :

```
lapply(df$seqs2, function(x) stringr::str_which(df$seqs2, x))
```

You can also use `grep` to keep this in base R :

```
lapply(df$seqs2, function(x) grep(x, df$seqs2))
```

Comment: Great, this worked like a charm. I tried lapply, but in a different way. But this gave exactly the result I needed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would there also be a method to combine this list as a output from lapply to my data frame?

If I grouped_by df$SNID? And mutated another column? I tried this, but it is having a hard time to recycle the list to size 1, which is quite understandable.. :D

Comment: Maybe like this? `df$result <- sapply(df$seqs2, function(x) toString(stringr::str_which(df$seqs2, x)))`